# Use CSS to separate groups of words and force line break

Tags: javascript, html, css, optimization

Here’s a challenge! I have a DIV that contains some text:

```
<div class="extended-text">One Two Three Four Five Six</div>
```

Without using HTML mark up, for example, breaks `<br>`, non breaking spaces `&nbsp;`, or similar, how do I cleverly use CSS preferably, or script as a last resort, to force a line break at the occurrence of a group of words?

---

For example, for this extended text:

***One Two Three Four Five Six***

Separate “*One Two*” from “*Three Four Five Six*” and force a line break, to display:

***One Two***

***Three Four Five Six***

---

Note: Have thought of using non breaking spaces and breaks in HTML, for instance below, but that’s going to be really messy.

```
<div class="extended-text">One&nbsp;Two<br>Three&nbsp;Four&nbsp;Five&nbsp;Six<div>
```

---

Thank you.

Comment: you would need to add extra html via script as css cannot do it with your current structure

Comment: Perhaps play with columns `div {
      width: 220px;
      height: 200px;
      column-count: 2;
      column-gap: 10px;
    }`

Comment: Hi, all. To those who have voted to close this question, please note that yes, I have tried my own challenge, yes did do research, couldn't find a solution, and have come to Stack Overflow for some guidance and support. I've made the question as simple and clear as possible to help assist in an answer. Just looking for a simple way to achieve a line break between groups of words without building unnecessary detail into HTML. Thank you.

Comment: If you are unable to alter the markup directly you’ll have to use JS to add markup (e.g. `<br>`). There’s no way to do this purely with CSS since `:nth-word` doesn’t exist…yet.

Comment: @user4806509  if you do not show your attempts then this looks like a please do my code for me question and therefore it is too broad and off topic for SO - if it is a question about your code not working, then it is off topic because you need to show the code that is not working in a [mcve]. Either way, your question is off topic in it's current form which is why you are gettting close votes

Answer (score 1):

You can do this quite simply with CSS. Here is one way.

```css
/* This will break the text after each span */
span::before {content: '\A'; white-space: pre;}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>One Two</span><span>Three Four Five Six</span>  
</div>
```